# test hybrid app on iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, hybrid

I have created a hybrid application (using html5 and jQueryMobile and Phonegap).

I am planning to make it as an iphone and ipad application. I could easily test in on android phone. But iphone I know it’s not directly possible. Please not that I haven’t created it in mac machine. From some research I got in order to test it on iphone / to get the .ipa file I need to register in apple developer program (which is paid $99).

Or can I build my application in xcode (my friend's mac machine) and get the .ipa file without registering to apple developer program?

Please guide me..

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to place your app into a device without Code Signing it, which means, you need to register as a developer.

You can, however, run your app on the simulator.

Comment: thanks for your reply..so suppose i register as a developer, then do I need a mac machine? I am thinking of developing the .ipa file using Phonegap build..

Comment: Yes, you will need a Mac in order to place your to build the .ipa from xcode.